# Kivy on Rpi : texture re-rendering

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have one big issue and I do not know how to solve it. I notice that when I change the colour of the text in CoreLabel simultaneously on more labels (one label by one) in a very short time, frame rate drop significantly. I only change the colour of the text. I read that this is a bottleneck of kivy, so I am wondering if there is any bypass way to speed up this?

Thank you.

```
#initialization
self.label_light = CoreLabel(text=str(self.num),font_size=22, bold=True, color=(.8, .8, .8, .8) )
self.label_light.refresh()
self.label_dark = CoreLabel(text=str(self.num), font_size=22, color=(0., 0., 0.,1.))
self.label_dark.refresh()

with self.canvas:
Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
self.num_rect = Rectangle(pos=((5, 48)), texture=self.label_light.texture,
                          size=self.label_light.texture.size)

#default is use light label
#changing label - select
self.rect.texture = self.label_dark.texture
#deselect
self.rect.texture = self.label_light.texture
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but since `kivy.core.text.Label` is not actually a GUI element, you might be able to do the color changing in a separate thread.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I see that I didn't right define a problem. I declare two labels, one with light and one with the dark text colour. Then I create a Rectangle and part of this rectangle is this label. Since I have a grid, in each square is one number. Primary is used light label when this address is called is used dark label. Only one address use dark label at the same time. ex. address 12 is called (the dark label is used), then 13 is called - 12  light, and 13 must use dark label. To switch between labels I used Rectangle - texture. These changes happening very often and GUI is not fast enough for rendering

Comment: I hope that this part will help. Each address (num) in GridLayout has the the same structure.